# Volume of a pyramid.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the pyramid with base in the plane $z=−9$ and sides formed by the three planes $y=0$ and $y−x=3$ and $2x+y+z=3$.

Comment: If you just google "Find the volume of the pyramid with base in the plane " there are a bunch of websites that show you how to do it. Here is one http://math.berkeley.edu/~scanez/courses/math53/spring06/problems/review2_solns.pdf

Comment: Despite the tag, this can be solved just with geometry.

Comment: @RossMillikan I have readded the tag because the OP (or others who may search this question) may be looking for an answer using multivariable calculus, though it may not be the simplest path.

Answer (score 3):

First find the coordinates of the corners of the base.  You are given $z=-9$ and have three lines in the plane.  If you solve each pair as a set of simultaneous equations, you get a point.  Those three points are the corners of the base.  What is its area?

To find the peak, solve all three equations as a simultaneous set.  They are designed to be easy.  The height of the pyramid is the distance from this point to the plane $z=-9$

The volume is then $\frac 13$(area of the base)(height)

Comment: Therefore the answer would be? im still having trouble. I appreciate the help

Comment: @Michael:  can you solve a pair of simultaneous equations?  One corner, coming from $y=0$ and $y-x=3$, is $(-3,0,-9)$.  Can you do the others?